# Why does a method call need to be disambiguated when it can in principle be a constant?

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax, constants

Method calls can usually omit the receiver and the parentheses for the arguments:

```
def foo; "foo" end
foo # => "foo"
```

In the case above, `foo` is ambiguous between method call and reference to a potential local variable. In the absence of the latter, it is interpreted as a method call.

However, when the method name can in principle be a constant name (i.e., when it starts with a capital letter, and consists only of letters), it seems to need disambiguation.

```
def Foo; "Foo" end
Foo # => NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
Foo() # => "Foo"
self.Foo # => "Foo"
```

Why is this the case? Why does a method call need to be explicitly distinguished from a reference to a constant even under the absence of a constant with the same name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of local variables which is in scope at any given point in the program is defined lexically and can thus be determined statically, even as early as parse time. So, Ruby knows even before runtime which local variables are in scope and can thus distinguish between a message send and a local variable dereference.

Constants are looked up first lexically, but then via inheritance, i.e. dynamically. It is not known which constants are in scope before runtime. Therefore, to disambiguate, Ruby always assumes it's a constant, unless obviously it isn't, i.e. it takes arguments or has a receiver or both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The fact that local variables are defined at parse time is the reason for the somewhat un-intuitive behavior of `if false then foo = 43 end; foo # => nil (instead of NameError)`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That makes perfect sense.

Comment: So its for efficiency?  In other words if we went willy nilly around having methods starting with capitals, then all these methods would have to go through the disambiguation process.  And given that if you need to for some reason, you an override the behavior (as shown in my answer)  GREAT ANSWER.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn: The *real* danger is that a third-party library you have no control about can change the meaning of your code just by introducing a constant somewhere up in the inheritance chain.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Gotcha - its worth explaining exactly how:  If I have a method Foo::Bar (that returns an array) but no class Foo::Bar then I may have a expression like this **Foo::Bar.each...** .  Now somewhere else the class Foo::Bar is defined, and suddenly  Foo::Bar.each stops working.  But let me ask:  Why is this any different if that library had simply opened Foo, and redefined Bar?

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn: Well, you can `freeze` the class, for one thing. But really, the difference is: things changing because you monkey-patch a method is expected. Things changing because you introduce a constant isn't. Note, it is not *just* about defining `Foo::Bar`. Also, defining a constant named `Bar` in *any superclass* of `Foo`, or in any module included by `Foo` or in any module included by any of the superclasses of `Foo` or in any module included by any module included by `Foo` or any of its superclasses or … Constants are looked up by inheritance, they can pop up far away!

Answer (score 2):

There's no big reason behind the difference. I just wanted foo to be behave like foo(), if there's no local variable foo in the scope. I thought it was useful for creating DSL etc. But I saw no reason to make Foo to behave like Foo().

Comment: What a surprise! 本物の松本さんですか。

Answer (score 0):

You ask a great question.  As you point out ruby wants to treat it as a constant and therefore do a constant lookup.

The following snippet however shows the current behavior, and then by modifying const_missing, you seem to get the desired behavior.  And to tell you the truth I can't seem to break anything.

My conclusion is that this was as somebody already suggested, just a design decision, but its odd because in general ruby favors convention vs enforcement.

Or I am missing some case where things do get confusing and the wrong thing happens.

```html
<script type="text/ruby">
def puts(s); Element['#output'].html = Element['#output'].html + s.to_s.gsub("\n", "<br/>").gsub(" ", "&nbsp;") + "<br/>"; end

class ImAClass
  def self.to_s
    "I am ImAClass Class"
  end
end

def ImAMethod
  "hello"
end

class DontKnowWhatIAm
  def self.to_s
    "a Class"
  end
end

def DontKnowWhatIAm
  "a method"
end

puts "ImAClass: #{ImAClass}" 

begin 
  puts "ImAMethod: #{ImAMethod}" 
rescue Exception => e
  puts "confusion! #{e.message}"
end

puts "ImAMethod(): #{ImAMethod()}"

puts "DontKnowWhatIAm: #{DontKnowWhatIAm}"

puts "DontKnowWhatIAm(): #{DontKnowWhatIAm()}"

class Module
  alias_method :old_const_missing, :const_missing
  def const_missing(c)
    if self.respond_to? c
      self.send c
    else
      old_const_missing(c)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  def self.Bar
    "im at the bar"
  end
end

puts "now we can just say: Foo::Bar and it works! #{Foo::Bar}"
 
</script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/reactive-ruby/inline-reactive-ruby/master/inline-reactive-ruby.js"></script>
<div id="output" style="font-family: courier"></div>
```